# Laravel 5.2 validation redirect

Tags: validation, redirect, post, laravel-5

Is it possible to redirect the user to a POST route in Laravel if validation fails?

```
Route::get('/order/confirm', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'PageController@orderConfirm']);
Route::post('/order/create', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'PageController@orderCreate']);
Route::post('/order/store', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'PageController@orderStore']);
```

I have 2 forms. First is confirm the order. Second is form containing the order.
If I give incorrect data in the order, shows an error message.

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
```

PS: I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change

```
Route::post('/order/create', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'PageController@orderCreate']);
```

to

```
Route::get('/order/create', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'PageController@orderCreate']);
```

it will work.